# Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) implementation below 4.3 (API 18)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I would like to know is it possible to implement the **BLE** in the device using OS of android **4.3/API 18**. Because in my requirement i have to implement **BLE** in mobile devices having OS version **4.0 - 4.2**, Any one having idea about this help.

Thanks regards.

Comment: I don't think is posible since the OS API's where introduced in 4.3? Maybe you can provide a fallback for devices that doesn't support it

Comment: you have to ask yourself if those devices (with 4.0-4.2) have BLE hardware support ... then even if they have ... only way is to upgrade OS version ...

Comment: Good luck with that! Who made up this magical requirement? Who will retrofit the hardware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible on specific devices, with very heavy fragmentation.

See:

- https://github.com/cjhuo/Android-Samsung-Ble-APIs-Bluez for Samsung devices with Android 4.1 e.g. some Galaxy S3 with original OS version.
- http://developer.samsung.com/ble for Samsung devices with Android 4.2 (e.g. Galaxy S4 with original OS version)
- https://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/bluetooth-smart/htc-ble-installation/ for HTC devices with Android 4.x

There may be more for other vendors...

I would advise sticking with Android 4.3 as much as possible, using the specific SDKs below 4.3 is a mess.

Comment: Hi Stéphane your answer was really help full, can you create a tag for me of "Metaio" i dont have that much point to create a new tag.

Comment: Hey glad it helped! what does "Metaio" mean?

Comment: Hi Stéphane 'Metaio' is an 'SDK' that is used for "augmented reality" project's . currently working on the project with this topic.

Comment: HI @Stéphane thanks for the help this is my question url:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396674/detection-of-different-shapes-dynamically-like-circle-square-and-rectangle

Comment: can you vote for this question to reopen URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572348/how-to-integrate-the-metaio-open-cv-for-android-application