# How to integrate the metaio + Open CV for android application?

Tags: android, opencv, integration, augmented-reality, metaio

Hi i'm trying to create a application related to the Augmented Reality (AR) and was able to configure my application with Metaio SDK and OpenCV library successfully in two separate application.

but the thing is i want to use both the library of OpenCV and Metaio together into one application. so can any one help me with its integration.

In my single application I want to use OpenCV for markerless detection and MetaIO for 3D Model rendering.

Metaio:http://www.metaio.com/

OpenCV:http://opencv.org/

=====>

I'm using opencv to detect shapes in a camera image and want to display 3D objects rendered by metaio on those shapes. Similar to marker tracking.

Metaio and openCV, each have their own cameraview. I have disabled cameraview of openCV.

I want to convert an ImageStruct object received in `onNewCameraFrame()` method into an OpenCV Mat in Android. For this, I have registered MetaioSDKCallback to continuously receive camera frame.

But `onSDKReady()` and  `onNewCameraFrame()` method of this callback is not being called,though I have added 'metaioSDK.requestCameraImage()'.

This where i'm stuck with it.

Comment: This the place where i have stuck with it.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to integrate the sdk of Opencv4android, and to see the samples come with, they are very good examples to teach you how to use the camera easily

For your objective probably face detection example is good to check.

[Here is the tuto](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) that help you to install and configure opencv SDK

For AR I can't help you so much, but have look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939318/augmented-reality-framework), it could be helpful.

Comment: appreciate your answer. I have gone through the all the tutorials of the Open cv as well as metaio i want both to be integrated under one roof (Project)